# Is it possible to debug in multiple browsers at the same time when I hit F5 in VS 2010?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I just want to test my code in multiple browsers at the same time, instead of right clicking on the aspx then clicking browse with... It's kinda frustrating me since my boss wants me to be fast always.

and please don't suggest copying the url then pasting it to the browser, because I already know that...

Comment: You can always change the default program to open aspx files to be a browser...

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/visual-studio/overview/2013/using-browser-link

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is indeed possible, here is a link to a simple guide that was designed for VS 2013 but should track up to 2017, [find it here.](https://dailydotnettips.com/2014/01/02/run-web-application-in-multiple-browser-simultaneously-from-visual-studio/)

Here are the important bits:

> When you select the “Browse With…” option, following dialog will
>   appear, and you can see all the list of browser along with the browser
>   which marked as “(Default)”.
>
> Now, there can be more than one default browser, and same has been
>   written in the dialog control as well – “Browsers (Select one or
>   more):” . So, select all the browser in which you want run the
>   application together, and click on “Set as Default”.  That’s all. Now
>   if you click on “Browse” button in the same dialog control, you will
>   find your web application starts on all the selected browser same
>   time.

This presents you with a 'multiple browsers' option for debugging.

**Note:**

As per Raniels comment below:

> visual studio 2010, I just pressed crtl + click browsers that I want
>   to set as default.

Comment: thanks a lot! What a convenient feature, that I didn't know that exists!

Comment: on visual studio 2010, I just pressed crtl + click browsers that I want to set as default.

Comment: @RanielQuirante good catch, hope you don't mind if I pop that as a note on the above answer.